# XCode Code Signing Customization

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, code-signing

I have been tasked with integrating our software builds with our key service environment (pretty much an HSM sitting behind a custom web service). I have successfully done this for Java and CNG but I don't know how to do this for our Mac environment and since I have never done any Mac or iOS development I am not even sure where to start. I have looked into XCode and some of Apple's code signing documentation but what I have seen so far seems to be specific to the private key residing on the file system of the local machine. Is there any way to use a remote private key? I want to intercept the call to generate the signature, offload it to our web service, then return the signature to the code signing client. Ideally, I would like this to work within the normal code signing environment that Mac developers use. Is such a "crypto-provider-plugin" possible? If so, could you point me to some developer documentation for it? It would be great if it could be developed in Java (since we have a huge amount of code already written in Java) but it is not a requirement.